# setDataSource failed con Xamarin Forms MediaElement

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to play youtube / vimeo videos using MediaElement from Xamarin.CommunityToolkit. Well: I always get, on Android, the error setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000 when adding the url of a youtube video to the MediaElement Source.

Permissions for Android.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Permissions for iOS.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
```

In iOS, the playback interface opens but I never get to play the video.

I also get this error from Android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Dsz.png)

Comment: Please provide us with a sample of your code, it will make it much easier for us to help

Comment: I only set the property Source of MediaElement with de url of the video. The code has no complexity

Answer (score 0):

I search some info and try to play Youtube video in MediaElement, but find you can not play it directly.
I find another way to do, you can install `YoutubeExplode`, convert that youtube video url into stream.

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="mediasample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit">
<xct:MediaElement
    x:Name="mediasource"
    AutoPlay="True"
    ShowsPlaybackControls="True"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetVideoContent();
    }
    private async void GetVideoContent()
    {
        YoutubeClient youtube = new YoutubeClient();
        // You can specify video ID or URL
        YoutubeExplode.Videos.Video video = await youtube.Videos.GetAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cld92SD0jrA");
        string title = video.Title; // "Downloaded Video Title"
        //string author = video.Author; // "Downloaded Video Author"
        TimeSpan duration = (TimeSpan)video.Duration; // "Downloaded Video Duration Count"
        //Now it's time to get stream :
        StreamManifest streamManifest = await youtube.Videos.Streams.GetManifestAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cld92SD0jrA");
        IVideoStreamInfo streamInfo = streamManifest.GetMuxedStreams().GetWithHighestVideoQuality();
        if (streamInfo != null)
        {
            // Get the actual stream
            System.IO.Stream stream = await youtube.Videos.Streams.GetAsync(streamInfo);
            mediasource.Source = streamInfo.Url;
        }
    }
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @iscalo DO you try my solution? having other question?

Comment: Sorry I was in vacation. I've tried your solution and works like a charm but it doesn't play vimeo videos. YoutubeExplode only works with youtube videos, obviously. I'll keep looking for a solution for vimeo videos. I hope find it soon

Comment: @iscalo Maybe you can use Webview to play vimeo videos.